# 'Error reading from database' in moodle

Tags: parameters, my.cnf

I am restoring a course 26.2MB in size in moodle 2.5 and am getting an 'Error reading from database' error. I am able to successfully restore a course 1.8MB in size. I have been searching around for solutions to my problem and the closest I came to solving it is this thread https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=230681 but I haven't been able to work out how to set parameters for MySQL as it appears it is related to max_allowed_packet setting in my.cnf file.  any help would be greatly appreciated. The version of PHP I am running is  4.0.8, latest stable version: 4.1.8 and I have access from WHM as well as CP

Many thanks.

ruth@whitewitch.ie

Comment: Add some code to your question showing exactly where you have problems.

Answer (score 1):

Just update MySQL :) and run install script again :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error ("error reading from database") and after long day unsuccessful search I realised that the drive on which MySql was running had ran out of space. When I freed up space it went back to normal. You have mentioned that you managed to restore a 1.8MB course but failing to restore the 26.2MB. It is most probable that you have limited storage space on your drive.